# Slow MySQL query for relatively small table with proper primary key and index

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have a select statement on 3 tables; T1 and T2 can be joined and T2 and T3 can be joined.  T3 is a table with 42 rows only.  T2 is really huge, about 4 billions rows and T1 is  750,000 records.  What I want is that for all the records in T1, I want to get relevant data from T3

If I do a join on all 3 tables like the following, the query takes a long time to run:

```
select T1.A, T2.B, T3.C, T3.D from 
T1, T2, T3 where T1.A = T2.A 
and T1.B = T2.B and T2.C = T3.C
```

But if I take out T3 from the query, the query ran much faster.  I also used `EXPLAIN` to find out the query path.  It looks like for T3, it's doing full table scan. i.e, the key column is NULL .

So, my question is why is it doing so?

T3 has a primary key and it's relatively small table.  Is my overall query slow because after T1 and T2 join, for all the remaining record, it's doing full table scan with T3?  So if there's 700,000 records after T1 and T2 join, then for each of those 700,000 records, it's fully scanning T3 tables.  So, it's like doing 700,000 x 42 scanning?

---

**UPDATE**:

I replaced my original table names with T1,T2,T3 for simpler understanding.  But here's my actual query:

```
select vc.vkey, vc.enst, vi.`effect_code`, te.effect, te.impact
from Variants vc, var_RVS.variant_impact vi, var_RVS.`types_effects` te
where vi.effect_code = te.eid
and vc.vkey = vi.vkey
```

And here's the output of the explain statement:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                       | key         | key_len | ref                             | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | te    | ALL  | PRIMARY                             | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                            |   42 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vi    | ref  | canonical_enst,vkey_idx,effect_code | effect_code | 4       | var_RVS.te.eid                  |  981 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vc    | ref  | allVsAllXref,vkey_enst              | vkey_enst   | 788     | var_RVS.vi.vkey,var_RVS.vi.enst |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Could you post your explain results?

Comment: also the schema would be helpful. is [A,B] a composite primary key?

Comment: Try to use JOINs instead of SQL in that syntax.

Comment: What evidence do you have that `te` (``T3`?) has any indices, or that `eid` (`C`?) is a primary key?

Comment: I looked at the table structure of T3 and ran 'show indexes' on T3.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is an index on T3.C, it has to scan all of T3 to find the records that satisfy `T2.C = T3.C`.  This has nothing to do with the key; its that there is no other way to find the records that satisfy this requirement, given your current schema (as far as I understand it).

Comment: T3.C is a primary key and an index as well.

Comment: @ayesandarmoe: And you didn't think that was relevant?

Answer (score 0):

At worst, the output will be 750K * 4B * 42 = 126 quadrillion rows.

The `EXPLAIN` estimates 42 * 981 * 1 = 40 thousand rows.

If there are cases where `vi.effect_code = te.eid` has no matching row, then the smaller number is possible.

You have nothing filtering out rows.  What do you expect?

The `EXPLAIN` shows that decent indexes exist at each stage, so the query is as fast as it can be.

How "slow" is slow?
How many rows do you get?